# InnoDB or MyISAM for sessions?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I'm using myisam tables for a website that i'm building, since it's going to be mostly read-only. And that is why i think myisam will be better. But i'm storing user sessions in a database ... so that means a select + update to the sessions table on every single page request. So with sessions i now have 1/1 reads/writes on the table and that could go higher on the writes if i need to update something on the session. Should i use innodb for such a table? Or is 1/1 read/write ratio still something that myisam has no problem with? The application will not have high traffic (although i'm not even sure what defines high traffic for this situation)

Comment: I'd say 'neither' actually: both are too slow if you're worrying about performance. Go with either MEMORY (engine) or Memcached/Redis (another RDBMS with in-memory storage).

Comment: what do you want to do with your sessions that the built-in PHP sessions do not support?

Comment: @RandomSeed ... store them in db. It's not a question about sessions, it's a question about storage engines. And sessions are the best example for this, but they are not the only situation where you would have ratios like 1/1. So let's not go off topic here.

Comment: Knowing your requirement can help in providing recommendations relevant to your purpose. The "best" storage engine is not the same if you are just trying to address a performance bottleneck, or if you want to allow for distributed sessions. My question was perhaps too laconic and misguiding.

Comment: @RandomSeed I guess my requirements are for the application to be able to handle a couple of dozen users per second at most. As far as sessions go, the question is pretty much answered, but i was kinda wanting to emphasize the 1/1 read/write ratio and not the sessions themselves, since unlike sessions, in some cases memory-related solutions cannot be used, because the data is important and should not be lost on server shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM is often faster than InnoDB in terms of raw performance (mostly because it is not ACID). Therefore accessing MyISAM *consumes less resources* than InnoDB.

On the other hand, MyISAM only supports table-level locking: in a highly concurrent environment, latency increases. A few dozen simple queries shouldn't cause too much trouble, however (assuming most of your queries would be a straightforward `SELECT session_data FROM session_table WHERE session_id = <some_id>`).

Conversely, InnoDB offers more robustness: it is virtually impossible for an InnoDB table to get corrupted, and the difference in terms of performance tends to get less and less significant (eg. see [this benchmark](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/05/22/mysql-and-the-ssb-part-2-myisam-vs-innodb-low-concurrency/)). Some would even argue that there is little reason to keep using MyISAM nowadays (InnoDB became the default storage engine in v5.5).

I am sorry for not providing a more definitive answer as to which is "faster". As always when it comes to performance optimisation, real-life tests must be carried out. Keeping in mind that you can switch engines very easily (`ALTER TABLE t ENGINE=[MyISAM | InnoDB]`), I suggest to try and see.

But considering your expected traffic, using the one or the other shouldn't make too big a difference.

Comment: It would be easy to switch, but some things like auto increment work differently in both engines. Not to mention deadlock detection on innodb. As for the "which one is faster" - i really don't care as long as everything runs in fractions of a seconds and not full seconds. And i was afraid that might start happening with myisam because of full table locks way too soon. Anyway, thanks for your input, i think your last sentence answers my question pretty well :)

Comment: There is one more thing to add: MyISAM can be optimized in case you do a lot of delete/insert queries and the space can be easily retrieved back. While InnoDB doesn't have optimize and the table keeps getting bigger. The only way to reduce its size is to remake the index file.

Answer (score 1):

You had many options and Mysql isn't the best one:

1. Save on disc its good options if you had hardware Raid, not good for replication.
2. Mysql - yes and no i used previously Mysql - Myisam and on 50 users table crash. So if you need you can use "[MEMORY (HEAP)"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-storage-engine.html) table
3. Some language like PHP+extension had own Session storage eq [WinCache Session Handler](http://php.net/manual/en/wincache.sessionhandler.php) - Manual
4. Most popular [Php+memcached session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946033/is-it-recommended-to-store-php-sessions-in-memcache)
5. You can use even Sqlite for Session storage, because you can. For me best options is Mongodb Session storage || [REDIS-SESSION-PHP](https://github.com/ivanstojic/redis-session-php)
6. Some people change serialize engine to " [igbinary](http://codepoets.co.uk/2011/php-serialization-igbinary/) " for better performance

Comment: From [CI manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver): "`Only MySQL and PostgreSQL databases are officially supported, due to lack of advisory locking mechanisms on other platforms.`"