# Memcache v/s redis for maintaining persistent sessions?

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis, memcached

I want to make persistent sessions on server i am using node.js with express and for that first i read about connect-redis [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis) and connect-mongo [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) i read that redis is faster then mongo that's why i decided to use it but now i also find a module named memcached [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached) i dont know which will be better for my project, also in mamcache is data stored in memory or where because if it is memory then it must be fastest.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already setup Redis then I would stick with it as it is very fast and easy to manage. MemCached and Redis are very similar when used for caching however the key difference is that Redis can be set to persist to disk in the background meaning that if the server goes down the data in memory can be reloaded.

Personally, I would not use MongoDb for session persistence for speed reasons however if I was using MemCached I'd possibly use it as a backup for the sessions. e.g. Write session data to MemCached and Mongo but only read from MemCached and use Mongo to restore is an error occurs.

Bottom line, I think your choice to use Redis is the best one for what you've described